# Cannot find -lInclude on server side

Tags: python, compilation, server, theano, gensim

After I installed the Theano and genesim by pip install xxx --user on server side, I tried to import them in python code, but I had this error:

Exception: Compilation failed (return status=1): /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lInclude. collect2: ld returned 1 exit status.

In addition, I have no root permission, how can I make it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [IPython module import error: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpython2.7. collect2: ld returned 1 exit status](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21644214/ipython-module-import-error-usr-bin-ld-cannot-find-lpython2-7-collect2-ld)